# passing function as a parameter to another function in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

Basicly,what I want to do is this:

I have a function square(x) `(define (square x) (* x x))`(f(x)=x*x),and another function mul_two `(define (mul_two x) (* 2 x))`(g(x)=2*x), I want to construct a new function based on the above two functions, what the new function does is this: `2*(x*x)`(p(x)=g(f(x))), how can I write this new function in scheme? Although its a pretty straight thing in mathmatical form I'm totally stuck on this .

Answer (score 3):

```
(define (new_fun x) (mul_two (square x)))
```

EDIT:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (mul_two x) (* 2 x))

(define (new_fun fun1 fun2) (lambda (x) (fun2 (fun1 x))))

((new_fun square mul_two) 10)
```

And you will get 200. (10 * 10 * 2)

Also, you can implement a general purpose *my-compose* function just as the *compose* in racket:

```
(define (my-compose . funcs)
  (let compose2
    ((func-list (cdr funcs))
     (func (lambda args (apply (car funcs) args))))
    (if (null? func-list)
      func
      (compose2
        (cdr func-list)
        (lambda args (func (apply (car func-list) args)))))))
```

And you can obtain new-fun by:

```
(define new-fun (my-compose mul_two square))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer~~  actually, the situation is this: I got two functions, one function is passed a parameter to the other function, then this newly generated function is passed to another function..  do you know how to do this in scheme?

Comment: @linuxfish, I changed my answer and in the new answer, new_fun is just a function combining fun1 and fun2. (new_fun square mul_two) is the new function you want.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do what you're asking is by using [`compose`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._compose%29%29), which according to the linked documentation:

> Returns a procedure that composes the given functions, applying the last `proc` first and the first `proc` last.

Notice that `compose` is quite powerful, it allows us to pass an arbitrary number of functions that consume and produce any number of values. But your example is simple to implement:

```
(define (square x)   ; f(x)
  (* x x))

(define (mul_two x)  ; g(x)
  (* 2 x))

(define p ; g(f(x))
  (compose mul_two square))

(p 3) ; same as (mul_two (square 3))
=> 18
```

If for some reason your Scheme interpreter doesn't come with a built-in `compose`, it's easy to code one - and if I understood correctly the comments to the other answer, you want to use [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Let's write one for the simple case where only a single value is produced/consumed by each function, and only two functions are composed:

```
(define my-compose ; curried and simplified version of `compose`
  (lambda (g)
    (lambda (f)
      (lambda (x)
        (g (f x))))))

(define p ; g(f(x))
  ((my-compose mul_two) square))

(p 3) ; same as (mul_two (square 3))
=> 18
```

Answer (score 0):

In #!racket (the language) you have `compose` such that:

```
(define double-square (compose double square))
```

Which is the same as doing this:

```
(define (double-square . args)
   (double (apply square args)))
```

If you want to use Scheme (the standard) you can roll your own:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

(define (compose . funs)
  (let* ((funs-rev (reverse funs))
         (first-fun (car funs-rev))
         (chain (cdr funs-rev)))
    (lambda args
      (fold-left (lambda (arg fun) 
                   (fun arg))
                 (apply first-fun args)
                 chain))))

(define add-square (compose (lambda (x) (* x x)) +))
(add-square 2 3 4) ; ==> 81
```